# PostgreSQL: Displaying result using RECORD type variable in function

Tags: postgresql, record, plpgsql

I am passing column name and table name as parameter to function for dynamic query as shown below in example.

Problem: While executing "SELECT" query within function, it only displaying the structure of the table not rows.

Example:

--Table

```
create table test1
(
   rollno integer,
   fname text,
   lname text,
   age integer,
   branch text,
   phno integer,
   email text,
   address text,
   city text,
   state text,
   country text
 );
```

--Inserting some rows

```
insert into tes1 values(1,'aaa','bbb',25,'CS',1234567890,'abc@gmail.com','sector1','xyz','zyx','yxz');

insert into tes1 values(2,'zzz','xxx',25,'EE',987654321,'zzz@gmail.com','sector2','uvw','wvu','vuw');
```

--Function

```
create or replace function fun1(colB text,vname varchar)
returns setof record as
$body$
declare 
       str text;
       grp text;
       addi text;
       sqlq varchar;
       tname varchar;
begin
       if colB='fname' then
         str:='fname';
         grp:='rollno'||','||'fname';
         addi:='city'||','||'state'||','||'country';
         tname:=vname;

       elsif colB='lname' then
         str:='lname';
         grp:='rollno'||','||'lname';
         addi:='city'||','||'state'||','||'country';
         tname:=vname;
       end if;

   raise info '%',str;
   raise info '%',grp;
   raise info '%',addi;
   raise info '%',vname;
   raise info '%',tname;

   sqlq:='select rollno,'||str||',age,branch,'||addi||' from '|| tname;
   raise info '%',sqlq;
   execute sqlq;    

end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

--Function calling

```
select * from fun1('lname','test1') as ("rollno" integer,"lname" text,
"age" integer,"branch" text,"city" text,"state" text,"country" text);

INFO:  lname
INFO:  rollno,lname
INFO:  city,state,country
INFO:  tes1
INFO:  tes1
INFO:  select rollno,lname,age,branch,city,state,country from tes1
rollno | lname | age | branch | city | state | country
--------+-------+-----+--------+------+-------+---------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must [return](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN58213) with the results inside a function (unless it's `RETURNS VOID`), like

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sqlq;
```

And, you *should* properly [escape](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) the column names, f.ex. with the [format()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function, like

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT "col1", %I FROM %I', 'col2', 'test1');
```

Comment: Sanitizing dynamic input is a must, but that only applies to the table name in this case (in the original example, the answer deviates). The double quotes around `"col1"` and the treatment of `col2` serve no purpose here - both being hard coded, legal, lower-case names. [More details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter they are just an example, how to use format function for this purpose.